# Tensorflow Object Detection API Detects Old Classes as My Custom Object

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am triying to create a custom object detector with Tensorflow Object Detection API. I followed the API documentation,and many other tutorials. I am using pre-trained faster rcnn model and default config file values (i edited "PATH TO BE CONFİGURED" areas correctly)(my label map has only one item and its id is 1). After training with 6660 training examples, results are not perfect but its okay for my test images. The main problem is when i test the model with different images that doesn't contain my custom object,  it detects other objects as my custom object. Especially, if the object is in coco dataset(my model pre-trained on coco dataset) like car, knife, laptop etc. model detecting their location and tagging them as my custom object. Is this a bug or am i missing something ?

My config file, label map,test code and files ı used for creating tf records are in here : https://github.com/mstferis/tensorflow_object_detection

[total loss graphic in tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8kWa.png)

with this model i take these outputs. It detects handguns (thats what i want) but it also detects other objects as handgun.

[false example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0cNl.png)

[false example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dYC.png)

[false example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc7Rs.png)

[true example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8po4I.png)

[true example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaMv7.png)

*Note (Update): Finally I added pictures of other classes to my training set and labeled them just as my custom object. Now model predicts less false positives. But i still couldn't find what was wrong before.

Comment: is there any code section where you facing this issue?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure I have added links for my files and results.

Comment: anybody help me?

Comment: I could not spot anything wrong on the coding side. There might be some ML issue here. You can try asking this as an ML question stats.stackexchange.com or maybe Quora.